# Multiplying 2 matrix using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I would just like to know why this returns an "Expected end of statement" whenever I call the function multiply_matrix(matrixA, matrixB) and feed it with matrixA (3x3 matrix), and matrixB(3x3 matrix).
The error is always at "Next k".

This is the code of the function.

```
Function multiply_matrix(matrixA, matrixB)

    dim answer_matrix(3,3)


    for i=0 to UBound(matrixA,1)

        for j=0 to UBound(matrixB,2)

            sum = 0

            for k=0 to UBound(matrixB,1)

                sum = sum +  ( matrixA(i,k) * matrixB(k,j) )

            next k  

            answer_matrix(i,j) = sum

        next j

    next i

    multiply_matrix = answer_matrix


End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other Basic dialects allow variable names after the `Next`, VBScript doesn't.